# Build and Archive Option in XCode and Submit to iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode

Although I have already submitted my app using Build And Archive and then clicking on the Submit to iTunes connect I will ask the question anyway. Apple says that select a Distribution profile when submitting to Apple. So, I went on iTunes and downloaded the Distribution profile. I added profile to xCode. I did the build and archive option then validated the application. Everything was validated successfully. Before submitting the application I noticed that there is a big question mark on the left hand side saying "Application Info". This is strange because I have already filled out all the name, description, version, keywords etc on the iTunes connect website. Anyway, I submitted the app and now it shows "Waiting for review".

Will the validation catch the exception if I try to submit the app for any profile other than the distribution? I am asking this because I have several profiles I created for BETA testing.

**UPDATE 1:**

One other thing I am noticing is that even though when I select the distribution profile and do build and archive. When I open the archive.plist file in the archive folder the XCProfileUUID value matches that of the Team Provisioning Profile and not to the distribution profile. Not sure what is that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation does not check, to my knowledge, *which* profile you built & signed with. It only checks that you selected a *valid* profile.

You must ensure that you have selected your distribution profile under Project > Select Active Build Configuration. There are a number of other application settings you need to verify are filled out properly.

Apple provides a great step-by-step Howto in one of the tabs online where you create & download your Distribution profile. As long as you followed those steps & properly set the Build Configuration, you should be golden.

Comment: I did select the correct distribution profile when submitting the app. I right clicked on targets and then selected build option and changed the profile to the correct one. I did build and archive and submitted the app. But after that when I opened xcode I saw the profile switched to something else.

Comment: Just so you can verify your build process is successful, it would be wise to view Apple's guide for distribution signing & submitting. 

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Comment: I do think I followed all those steps. But as I said in the end I used Build and Archive option to submit my application to iTunes. I guess I will wait and see! Thanks!

Comment: One other thing I am noticing is that even though when I select the distribution profile and do build and archive. When I open the archive.plist file in the archive folder the XCProfileUUID value matches that of the Team Provisioning Profile and not to the distribution profile. Not sure what is that??

Comment: I personally handle this via Configurationss. Every project has a Debug & Release configuration by default (found via right-click on project & clicking the Configurations tab). Duplicate Release configuration and call it Distribution. Click the Build tab & modify all settings there for distribution--including selecting Distribution profile in the Code Signing Identity section. Once set, right-click Targets > appName and ensure it is set to Distribution configuration & that properties are correct.

Comment: I am pretty sure I followed all the steps correctly! Any idea about the XCProfileUUID attribute in the archive.plist as I mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure on the XCProfileUUID matter. I'd have to hunt around a .plist for a submitted app and see what I find. If you are very concerned, you could always follow carefully thru the Distribution guidelines, check and double-check and check everything again, rebuild, and reject your prior binary before re-submitting. :)

Answer (score 1):

The validation would not have passed if it was incorrectly signed.

Comment: Thanks! So, I guess it means I submitted the correct distribution + correctly signed app to app store.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is too late to talk about a solution of the issue. Anyways, based on my personal experience, the big question mark in the "Build & Archive" screen indicates that you have not explicitly specified the icon name for the "Icon file" key in the info.plist file of your app. Don't worry, this issue only relates to the "Build & Archive" screen, and your submitted app is still as good without the explicit declaration of icon file, rest assured!